# php connection error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

```
Could not connect Server:
Access denied for user 'markwayt_mar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When I run PHP  index file I get the above error. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: How about answer acceptance error?

Comment: There's got to be a `0` somewhere you aren't paying attention to.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Mysql password is wrong. Check `config.php` file

Comment: Or the username doesn't exist

Comment: permissions could also be incorrect. what makes you think he has a config.php?